# Please explain the foreign_key and local_key in Laravel ORM relationships

Tags: orm, laravel-4

I'm effectively trying to define the relationships between users (sender and recipient) and messages.

My Messages migration is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('messages', function($t){
            $t->increments('id');
            $t->integer('sender_user_id')->unsigned();
            $t->integer('recipient_user_id')->unsigned();
            $t->string('subject');
            $t->text('content');
            $t->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::dropIfExists('messages');
    }

}
```

My Message model was straightforward:

```
<?php

class Message extends Eloquent{
    // link to sender user id
    public function from(){
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'sender_user_id'); 
    }
    // link to recipient user id
    public function to(){
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'recipient_user_id');
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure in defining the `hasMany` relationships in my User model.

The docs (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) shows the following:

```
return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Now, I'm confused which key is which in the latter `hasMany` relationship. Which is correct for my User model?

```
public function sentMessages(){
    return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'id', 'sender_user_id');
}

public function sentMessages(){
    return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'sender_user_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set your relation like this:

```
public function sentMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'sender_user_id');
}

public function receivedMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'recipient_user_id');
}
```

Comment: Does Eloquent know to use id on User?

Comment: Yes. By default, primary keys are known by Laravel as id, if you have a different name for the primary key on User, you have to set it as the $primaryKey property on the User model. But, in the two cases, you don't have to set it in the hasMany function call as Laravel know to pick the default one or from the $primaryKey property of the model